# How can I deal with cats who dig into plant soil (indoor)?

Tags: indoors, soil

My cat loves digging into my plant pots, spreading soil everywhere, and destroy my plant roots... I have tried the educational way, and since then he stopped practicing when I'm around, but he can't stand doing "tunnels" when I'm away...

How can I avoid this?

I've tried

- to put some orange skins on the soil surface as a repellent, but the efficiency is pretty low...
- to cover the soil with a ground-cover plant, but the plant did not survive the attacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I densely covered the soil with one or two layers of oval 40/60mm marble pebbles for the biggest pots and with 25/40mm marble pebbles for the smaller pots.

It is very efficient to discourage the cat digging, because it requires lots of effort.

Pebbles are preferred to standard rocks, because its smoothing makes it slippery, then the holes usually get instantaneously filled with nearby pebbles while the cat is digging.

[image]